# TCPDF open pdf links in new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tcpdf, new-window

How to open links (in pdf document) in new tab or window by using javascript ?

This one is not working :

```
<a href=\"javascript: w=window.open('http://google.com') w.print(); w.close();\">Click</a>
```

This one is not working too :

```
$js = <<<EOD
function openw(url) {
    app.window.open(url,"PDF");
}
EOD;

$pdf->IncludeJS($js);
```

The sample of above: `<a href="javascript:openw(http://google.com)" target="_blank">Click</a>`

Any advice or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove backslashes and you forgot a semicolon after `w=window.open('http://google.com')`:

```
<a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://google.com'); w.print(); w.close();">Click</a>
```

If you want to open the window and print it and then close it again, then this one should work.

Comment: in internet explorer print(); doesn't work so you will have to click the print button of the browser to print the page

Comment: maybe you should try to load the print() function inside of the new window when it has loaded

Comment: I'm not interested with printing page. I found that code from somewhere and It was worked with Opera. So I can delete print() function. I only want to open links in new window which are in pdf document. P.S. : PDF document open with web browser.